# Suitable distance metric for time-series clustering with respect to location of shapes

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, distance

I'm doing clustering on time-series (each time-series has the information for one day = 24 hours). For the clustering purpose, it's important for me to consider the **time period** in which the shape of time-series is different from the baseline. So, I'm looking for an appropriate distance metric.

For example, let's consider these 4 time-series, and I want to cluster them into two groups.

[image]

Apperaently, for k=2, time-series 1 and 2 are more similar and considered as one cluster and time-series 3 and 4 are inside another cluster. However, when I use the commonly used Euclidean distance metric, the calculated distance between all time-series is the same since it considers one to one mapping between points, and does not account for how far these shapes are. I have tried [Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) as well since its application matches what I want to do here, but my clustering results in a larger-scale dataset are even less promising compared to what Euclidean distance obtains (I'm using the default [MATLAB command line](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dtw.html) for DTW, so I'm not sure if I'm utilizing it efficiently).

My question is what distance metric is more appropriate to capture the similarity in this case.

Comment: Are 1 and 4 in one cluster because they occur during the night/dark? (Wraparound)

Comment: That's an interesting point you brought up! But at this time I'm considering each time-series as 24 points (starting from 1 to 24) and just looking for a metric that shows me the distance between #4 and #3 is lower compared to #4 and #2 or #4 and #1 based on visual intuition.

Comment: Have you checked the dtwclust package - https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust

Comment: How about the integral of t * f(t)

Comment: (Or in your case, sum(n * f(n)), n ranging from 1 to 24)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor point, DTW is not a metric, just a measure.

The measure you need is constrained DTW (or cDTW),

With enough data you can learn the constraint, but here is it clear it should be about 1/3 the length of the time series.

This tutorial will tell you all you need to know
http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf

eamonn