# Clustering visited vertex in a graph

Tags: r, clustering, python, matlab, similarities

I would like to know can anyone introduce me an algorithm to cluster multiple sequence of visited vertices in a graph. For example assume your graph has 6 nodes.
following might be 3 different sequences:

```
2 3 3 4
1 2 4 5 6
1 3 5 6 6 6
```

I am looking for to see how to cluster something like above. So two graph might be similar if they share the same nodes with similar ordering (not necessarily the same) .

Can anyone give an algorithm to do that. Has anything like this implemented in any package in R, Python or Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

To cluster data samples you need to define a [dissimilarity measure](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/node/3/).

Depending on your choice which samples should be considered similiar - the dissimilarity measure should be chosen.

(a) If you give importance to the ordering of the nodes visited - then i suggest to look into "[time series clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series+clustering)"

In your case I recommend to use DTW as suggested in the answer to this    question: [Suitable distance metric for time-series clustering with respect to location of shapes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358003/suitable-distance-metric-for-time-series-clustering-with-respect-to-location-of)

(b) If you give importance only to "which nodes have been visited", then i suggest to encode the samples differently. For each sample, you create an array with the length of the number of all nodes in the network. Each position is a boolean (1 - true, 0 - false) which indicates whether or not this node has been visited.

2 3 3 4   - 0 1 1 1 0 0

1 2 4 5 6 - 1 1 0 1 1 1

1 3 5 6 6 6 - 1 0 1 0 1 1

Then finally you can choose an algorithm for clustering - which all have their [pros and cons](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

Comment: Thanks .I really appreciate it. when you code it a 0 or 1. then what do these sequence represent? are they distances ? because for all these clustering algorithms the rows are observations and the columns are the features. Therefore rows make sense but what about columns what do they represent?

Comment: Each column represents a node. For each observations (row) each has either been visited (1) or not (0). This is just an example for a possible encoding. One of the disadvantages of this specific encoding is that the order is nodes visited is neglected as well as the count of visits per node. (12345 = 51234 = 5511223344 === 1 1 1 1 1)

Comment: Does your DTW work if we revisit some vertices again suppose we have 1 2 2 2 and 1 2 1 1?